# Can not pass (or read) environment variables from docker + .net core

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, environment-variables

.Net core 5.0.103

docker version: 20.10.2, build 2291f61  (Ubuntu)

I create docker image + try to get environment variables from command line.
So:

```
docker run -it --rm robust_tapir -e ADDRESS='127.0.0.1' -e Port='5000' -e Schema='http'
```

And result is:

```
[15:08:57 ERR] Hello World!
[15:08:57 ERR] Address:
[15:08:57 ERR] Port:
[15:08:57 ERR] Schema:
```

In my .net core console app:

```
            Logger = CreateLogger();
            Logger.Error("Hello World!");

            await Task.Delay(5);

            Address = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ADDRESS");
            Port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Port");
            Schema = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Schema");
       
#if DEBUG
            Address = "127.0.0.1";
            Port = "5000";
            Schema = "http";
#endif
            Logger.Error($"{nameof(Address)}:{Address}");
            Logger.Error($"{nameof(Port)}:{Port}");
            Logger.Error($"{nameof(Schema)}:{Schema}");

            while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address))
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000);
            }
```

So, what i do wrong? Wrong pass into container or wrong read it from .net core?

Comment: Try removing single quotes surrounding 127.0.0.1, 5000 and http.

Comment: I had the same issues and I moved the image name to the end of the line and it fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quotes goes around the entire env. argument:

```
docker run -it --rm robust_tapir -e "ADDRESS=127.0.0.1" -e "Port=5000" -e "Schema=http"
```